# draft-js for multiline array of editors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to create a multi-line array of inputs within which I could edit the code using draft-js. How can I change the code below to access and write data to an array element?

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { EditorState } from 'draft-js';
import { Editor } from 'react-draft-wysiwyg';
import { convertToHTML } from 'draft-convert';
import DOMPurify from 'dompurify';
import 'react-draft-wysiwyg/dist/react-draft-wysiwyg.css';
import './App.css';
const App = () => {
  const [editorState, setEditorState] = useState(
    () => EditorState.createEmpty(),
  );
  const  [convertedContent, setConvertedContent] = useState('');
  const handleEditorChange = (state: React.SetStateAction<EditorState>) => {
    setEditorState(state);
    convertContentToHTML();
  }
  const convertContentToHTML = () => {
    let currentContentAsHTML = convertToHTML(editorState.getCurrentContent());
    setConvertedContent(currentContentAsHTML);
  }
  const createMarkup = (html: string | Node) => {
    return  {
      __html: DOMPurify.sanitize(html)
    }
  }

console.log(convertedContent);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        Rich Text Editor Example
      </header>
      <Editor
        editorState={editorState}
        onEditorStateChange={handleEditorChange}
        wrapperClassName="wrapper-class"
        editorClassName="editor-class"
        toolbarClassName="toolbar-class"
      />
      <div className="preview" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup(convertedContent)}></div>
    </div>
  )
}
export default App;
```

The attached code implements the draft-js structure itself with a text control panel, as well as translating value into html and then displaying it in textarea

Comment: `convertedContent` contains the text of editor. now you want to put it on an array? do you have multiple editors and you want to have an array of their values?

Comment: Yes, I created a dynamic form where you can add some text sections and now I'm trying to connect draft-js to them